# What iOS versions support ARC with __weak designators?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I thought that the __Weak designator would only work on iOS5 where you would have to use __unsafe_unretained on previous iOS versions. But in this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543037/904972 NJones implies that iOS 4.3+ handles __weak references whereas you have to use __unsafe_unretained on iOS < 4.2. Is this the case or am I misunderstanding the post. If it is the case can you provide a link to an "official" answer from apple.

Comment: I think they were just implying 4.x as a whole doesn't support `__weak`. I believe they just used 4.2 as an example because that was the last 4.x version supported for iPhone 3G-class devices which cannot be upgraded to iOS 5.0.  Every device that supports 4.3 should be upgradable to 5.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Comment: How can things work well if weak references are not supported in iOS 4? When using ARC, I typically have weak references in the View Controllers. Does that just mean use the property annotation of "assign" ?

Comment: @finneycanhelp you can use unsafe_unretained instead of weak.