# iOS - Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) vs Manual Retain-Release (MRR)

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Few months back, when I started developing apps for iOS (I was experienced Java Developer), my colleagues who were experienced in iOS warned me to stay away from ARC (as they claim its kinda buggy). Now I'm pretty comfortable with MRR. But I want to move on to ARC if it really worths. While looking in Apple's documentation i.e. ["About Memory Management"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). I found:

"If you plan on writing code for **iOS**, you must **use explicit memory management**"

So I'm still confused whether to go for ARC or not. I am only concered about iOS (not Mac development).

Thanks.

Comment: unless you are mixing with Core Foundation objects, I can't see any reason *not* using ARC

Comment: Im a professional iOS developer and I use ARC. Never had any problems so far. Since making the change from manual memory management I haven't looked back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your colleagues don't sound experienced with iOS.  ARC isn't buggy.  Every single experienced iOS developer I've heard mention ARC has done so in approving terms.  I have over three year's experience with iOS and I would strongly recommend ARC, so long as you actually understand what's going on under the hood.  Apple themselves, in the very guide you link to say:

> You are strongly encouraged to use ARC for new projects.

When Apple say that you must use explicit memory management, they are grouping traditional manual memory management and ARC together as explicit memory management, in contrast to garbage collection.

Also, note that you linked to documentation in the Mac developer library, not the iOS developer library.  If you need to develop for iOS, use the iOS developer library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did pointed to MAC docs intentionally because that statement was confusing me, but now I'm clear (credit goes to you).

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion is that you should start learning to use ARC and implement them in your own projects (unless for some reason your client/boss doesn't want). More and more libraries are being created and converted to use ARC. Apple also advises you to use ARC in your own projects (see Jim's answer). Although I must insist that **any person that starts learning objective-c and iOS should become familiarized with the traditional memory management** and then  go to ARC. Also, you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542718/starting-with-objective-c-to-arc-or-not-to-arc).

Answer (score 2):

go for ARC as it in some cases give boost to application's performance  read the blogs below

- http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/
- http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

and many more

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little experienced programmer, but from my point of view, ARC allows you to save a lot of time since you don't worry about `retain`/`release` objects and implement `dealloc` methods. In addition it lets you to think in terms of **object graph**. In this case you need to make attention to cycles within your application.

Out of there there a lot of tutorials on how to migrate to ARC. Here my favorites:

1. http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html
2. http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/migrating-your-code-to-objective-c-arc/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been experienced with MMR and probably aware of how tedious task memory management could become.  When using ARC there is no need for retain and release calls, and not only that in many cases ARC can provide a significant performance increase.

Personally, I feel that if you're using a lot of C libraries in your code, ARC is a little bit harder to use right now (so if you're mostly using third-party C libraries and things like CoreFoundation, you might consider whether it makes sense or not), but even then, if these libraries are mostly isolated from your Objective-C controllers and such, ARC is still good.

Follow this guide: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/